# How/When to physically remove a failing harddrive after replacing it in a Linux RAID?

Tags: raid, hard-drive, software-raid, mdadm

I have a Linux software RAID-1 with mdadm. Similar to this question ("[How to safely replace a not-yet-failed disk in a Linux RAID5 array?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74924/how-to-safely-replace-a-not-yet-failed-disk-in-a-linux-raid5-array)"), I want to replace a disk in a the raid.

My question might be stupid, but I want to be *100% sure* that I don't mess things up. **My question is how exactly do I remove (physically etc.) the old disk?** I've never done this before and afraid I might make a newbie mistake and lose lots of data.

> Once the operation is complete, the former spare (here: sdc1) will become active, and the failing drive will be marked as failed (F) so you can remove it.

Does this mean that I can/should:

1. Power off the machine
2. Physically remove the old disk
3. Boot up the machine.
4. And the RAID array will now only have 2 disks (one old and one new).

Comment: As you've seen having a spare disk is useful, you should plan on adding a new one during the maintenance window you use to remove the failed drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your operation plan is OK.

The only addition to it is that after having removed the disk and rebooted the machine, you will have a disk in the "failed" state. To completely remove any reference to such disk, you had to issue the following command:

`mdadm <mdarray> --remove <faileddisk>`

Obviously, substitute  and  with the read device names.

A suggestion: if you can, simulate it using looback device and/or virtual machines. When you have enough confidence in the process, issue it on the real hardware.